# DBF/Foxpro - super slow queries through the network

Tags: database, foxpro, dbf

I have an app that conducts queries on multiple DBF files over local area network.

However, the queries are extremely slow (up to 5 minutes on some files). They work quite fast locally, but since this app is going to be distributed to several customers we must account for those who have their DBFs in a remote machine.

What can I do to speed up these queries? I've already turned off oplocks, I repacked the DBFs, there's no antivirus running, and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of FoxPro you're using, or what client and server operating systems are involved, or what sort of network connection is involved.

On up to date Server 2008 R2 or later, with up to date Windows 7 SP1 or later clients **you do not need to (and indeed should not) mess with OpLocks**. In fact, you can't turn them off anyway without forcing the server back to SMB1, and you **really** don't want to do that.

The absolute first thing you should do before messing with anything infrastructural is make sure all your queries are [Rushmore optimised](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f5d2sa3(v=vs.80).aspx) because as with any database you need to take advantage of indexes. Have you done that?

Comment: Just to add to Alan's comments, use SYS(3054) to find out how well optimized your queries are. This article from my site shows you how to use it and to understand the results: http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Articles/Make%20Your%20Queries%20Fly.pdf